# How to show all products with pagination in magento?

Tags: php, magento

I am very new to magento. I think am using version 1.9. I want to show all products with pagination in home page. What is the path for controller, model, view? and where to am i work? please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `CMS->Manage Pages` in your magneto backend and select `Home Page` from the list of pages.

Use this code in the content field to show all products

```
{{block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_homepage" template="catalog/product/new.phtml"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to

```
put limit="All" in xml
```

**As Ex:**

```
{{block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_homepage" template="catalog/product/new.phtml" limit="all" }}
```

For